# Database.SqlQuery thread safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework-5

Does anybody know if [Database.SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) does something under the hood that would make it thread-unsafe (like creating or enlisting a transaction, etc.)?

This is the piece of code that I have to call from multiple threads - the query is very straight-forward, hardcoded (no access to shared user-code data):

```
public virtual long GetId(string sql)
{
    var newid = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<long>(sql).First();
    return newid;
}
```

My goal is to get by during a minor release - then we will have a chance to properly implement synchronization if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since ADO.NET employs [connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) and creating a new `DbContext` is relatively light-weight, you are safe to create a lot of contexts which can be disposed after using them.

So I would consider creating a new `DbContext` in a using block instead of using the field/property.

To answer your first question, running a query like the code in your question will only execute the statement against the database, as you would do in an old fashioned ADO.NET way.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is good, but I was surgically asking if any of the operations performed are thread-unsafe, hoping that somebody who has looked at the framework code may know.